# Singularitygs in sass format?

Tags: sass, singularitygs

Is it possible to use singularitygs in sass format rather than SCSS format?

Both singularitygs and breakpoint seems to come with only SCSS format files.  If I manually convert the provided files to sass format, will that work?

I tried setting default format to sass in the config.rb file but that just seems to cause errors when starting to watch.

Answer (score 1):

In Compass projects, you can interchange .sass and .scss files in the same project. Import them normally and you'll be OK.

That being said, as of this writing, both require custom Ruby functionality so in order to actually use either Breakpoint or Singularity, you need to be using them as Compass extensions as prescribed in their respective README files.

Comment: I am running into an error so I will go back and check out the README files.  I also didn' realize that one can mix SCSS and sass files together.  I will try it this morning.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. I used a switch `--syntax sass` to format a project in sass rather than SCSS:

   ```
   compass create {project name} -r singularitygs --using singularitygs --syntax sass
   ```
2. SCSS and sass format can be mixed in different files but the `watch` function will not automatically compile the other format.  For instance, if you set the default format to sass then any save to SCSS files will not be automatically processed.
3. The main reason I was getting the errors were from trying to install extension for compass.app. I am not sure what I am doing wrong but just copying singularitygs and breakpoint to the compass.app extension folder creates **error on compass.app as well as the compass command line execution.**

Comment: What you're doing wrong is that currently, both Breakpoint and Singularity require a little bit of Ruby code and as such you cannot simply copy their Sass files and use them. Once they are updated to Sass 3.3, any compatible compiler will be able to use just the Sass code, but only with compilers compatible with Sass 3.3